# Jenkins Kubernetes plugin: pending All nodes of label are offline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster that I want to work with jenkins. I have configured jenkins plugin to successfully authenticate with kubernetes cluster, but for some reason when I try to run the build it says all nodes are offline. My config: 
[image]

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a jenkins kubernetes plugin bug. Kubernetes v1.5.1 has this issue working with the plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40503.

Poking into jenkins logs gave me a hint:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud.addProvisionedSlave(KubernetesCloud.java:592)
        at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud.provision(KubernetesCloud.java:463)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$StandardStrategyImpl.apply(NodeProvisioner.java:701)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:307)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.access$000(NodeProvisioner.java:60)
        at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker.doRun(NodeProvisioner.java:798)
        at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```